# Quantile calculation in excel have not found

Tags: excel, calculation, normal-distribution, quantile, quartile

Quantile calculation in excel, is there a way to do that? I have values that I want to calculate the quantile(0.05, 0.50, and 0.95). I have tried search online but all i found is quartile calculations, not quantile. Most of info i got online cannot solve the problem. The reason I want this is to cross check values from python calculation results. Looking forward for any help.

In my excel, I have all the values in column "G", as example:
I want to calculate the quantile(0.05, 0.5, and 0.95) of all values in "G" column.
I want to calculate in excel...is there ways to do that? thanks

[image]

Comment: Show your input then output to excel cells.

Comment: In my excel, I have all the values in column "G", as example:
I want to calculate the quantile(0.05, 0.5, and 0.95) of all values in "G" column.
I want to calculate in excel...is there ways to do that? thanks

G
1.09936E-08
1.24831E-08
1.02066E-08
1.10457E-08
9.93788E-09
1.25035E-08
1.06305E-08
1.24135E-08
4.48602E-08
1.23504E-08
1.09763E-08
1.06166E-08
1.14301E-08
1.1502E-08
1.0383E-08
1.16946E-08

Comment: Put a screenshot here then show your desired output.

Comment: I updated my post with image to help more clearer info.

Comment: You can use the percentile.inc or percentile.exc functions. These should be equivalent to Python's inclusive or exclusive functions, but as noted here there are many different quantile formulas https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile

Comment: There is  no quantile calculation in excel...Only quartile is available.

Answer (score 0):

An old post, but for anyone else, I've used Percentile in the past and it's worked for what I've wanted to do.

```
PERCENTILE.INC(G2:G20,0.1)
```

This will give the 10% value.